# A model for a theory supporting AND and OR?

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory

Is the following statement true or false?

"There exists a finite set $S$ closed under the binary operations $*,+$ such that ... etc:"
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}{}
(\exists S, +, *) & & &\\
& |S| \in \mathbb{N} & & &\text{(the set $S$ is finite)} \\
& (\forall x,y,z \in S) \\
&& x+y &\in S &\text{($S$ is closed under $+$)}\\
&& x*y &\in S &\text{($S$ is closed under $*$)}\\
&& x+y&=y+x &\text{(commutativity of $+$)} \\
&& (x+y)+z&=x+(y+z) &\text{(associativity of $+$)}\\
&& (x*y)*z&=x*(y*z) &\text{(associativity of $*$)}\\
&& z*(x+y)&=(z*x)+(z*y) &\text{($*$ is right-distributive over $+$)}\\
&& (x+y)*z&=(x*z)+(y*z) &\text{($*$ is left-distributive over $+$)}\\
& (\exists T,F,\alpha_1,\beta_1,\gamma_1,&\\
& \alpha_2,\beta_2,\gamma_2 \in S)\\
&& T &\neq F &\text{(distinct $T,F$)}\\
&& \alpha_1*F+&\beta_1*F+\gamma_1=F&\text{( $F \land F = F$)}\\
&& \alpha_1*F+&\beta_1*T+\gamma_1=F&\text{( $F \land T = F$)}\\
&& \alpha_1*T+&\beta_1*F+\gamma_1=F&\text{( $T \land F = F$)}\\
&& \alpha_1*T+&\beta_1*T+\gamma_1=T&\text{( $T \land T = T$)}\\
&& \alpha_2*F+&\beta_2*F+\gamma_2=F&\text{( $F \lor F = F$)}\\
&& \alpha_2*F+&\beta_2*T+\gamma_2=T&\text{( $F \lor T = T$)}\\
&& \alpha_2*T+&\beta_2*F+\gamma_2=T&\text{( $T \lor F = T$)}\\
&& \alpha_2*T+&\beta_2*T+\gamma_2=T&\text{( $T \lor T = T$)}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

I make no other assumptions like neutral elements or inverses...
I also do not assume $\alpha$'s, $\beta$'s, $\gamma$'s, $T$ and $F$ to be necessarily distinct, with the exception that $T$ and $F$ must be distinct!

**Trying to find and example:**

I have used the `alg` software package (http://math.andrej.com/2011/01/22/alg/) before to find simpler structures, but I fail to find an example of this structure (keeps running). Can someone suggest perhaps an optimized algorithm for searching a model/example?

If I omit either the 4 $\land$ or the 4 $\lor$ conditions then models are immediately found. But the combination remains elusive.

**Trying to find a contradiction, to prove no such model exists**

I can prove that $F+F=F+T$, by adding together the 2nd and 3rd rules of the 4 $\land$ rules as a left-hand-side and the 1st and 4th as right-hand-side.

Similarily for the $\lor$ rules I can prove $T+T=F+T$.

Together I know that $F+F=F+T=T+T$ but I fail to prove a contradiction...

Can you prove the original statement false (and hence no such structure could exist) or alternatively provide an example/model for this theory, proving that such a structure does exist?

**EDIT:**

I contacted Andrej Bauer from the link above, seeking help with `alg` usage, to optimize the search. He was kind enough to not only restructure the $\land$ and $\lor$ equations in the `*.th` file for more efficient searching, but also kind enough to post [a rephrased version of my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270983/affine-embedding-of-the-two-point-lattice-into-a-semiring-like-structure) on the research-level mathoverflow exchange. However in our email discussion we were focused more on the affine relations and I failed to emphasize and highlight my $*$ is not required to be commutative. However Keith Kearnes found an elegant proof that such a structure can not exist if $*$ is commutative. So my original question (this page) remains unsolved, but we do know that if such a structure exists its $*$ can not be commutative.

**EDIT 2:**

We can also conclude $\alpha_1\neq\beta_1$ since if we assume they were equal then all left-hand-sides of  the $\land$ equations would equal $\alpha_1*(F+T)+\gamma_1$ contradicting the requirement that their right hand side differ for the 1st and 4th $\land$ rules. Similarly $\alpha_2\neq\beta_2$.

Comment: Do you want to say that "there exists a finite set $S$ with internal operations $+, *$ such that ..."? It might be a good idea to say so in english.

Comment: Yes, is the current wording better, or should I describe all the rest in prose as well? The reason I chose to formalize my question like this is because different people in different contexts use differing definitions of ring-like structures etc

Comment: Why do you want such an object? If your goal is just to find a "ring-like" algebraic structure which has operations representing $\land$ and $\lor$, why not work with a Boolean algebra directly?

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: "why?" as in making sure this is not a case of XY problem? or are you asking what application domain this would be useful for?

Comment: I'm just curious about the motivation, and specifically the motivation for wanting a model satisfying these particular axioms instead of the axioms for a Boolean algebra or Boolean ring.

Comment: The application domain is frequency-domain "Time-of-Flight" sensors, in the context of "medical" imaging, to image brain waves for BCI's. Reading the frequency-domain ToF literature, a specific recurring trade-off, where one facet can be improved at the expense of another, is assumed without proof. I hypothesized a structure which IF it exists, would render the trade-off imaginary. I carefully culled and weakened the axioms (originally I even assumed $*$ commutative, but realized it was not necessary before posting here) until I was left with the structure description above.

Comment: Also, I can not imagine someone who only needed say a Boolean ring, and knew the symbols $\land$ and $\lor$, would come up with such a contrived description. Even though I am not a mathematician, you can safely assume that if I require certain axioms, that I do in fact require them :)

Comment: You asked on MO what do I mean by taking congruence quotient. It is this: take the free algebra $A:={\mathbb N}[T,F,\alpha_1,...]$ on the variables $T$, $F$, $\alpha_1$, $\beta_1$, etc.; imposing first half of your identities means its elements will be polynomials in these variables, i. e. will have form $kT+lF+m\alpha_1+...+nT^pF^q\alpha_1^r+...$, where $k$, $l$, $m$, ..., $n$, $p$, $q$, ... are natural numbers. Then, to impose the remaining equalities, you start with the subset of $A\times A$ consisting of pairs $(f,g)$ for each of your equalities of the form $f=g$

Comment: (like e. g. $(\alpha_1F+\beta_1F+\gamma_1,F)$, etc.). You then generate from this subset the smallest subalgebra of $A\times A$ which at the same time is an equivalence relation. This means to add to this subset all pairs $(f,f)$, then, if pairs $(f1,g1)$ and $(f2,g2)$ are there, also add the pair $(f1f2,g1g2)$, then if $(f,g)$ is there also add $(g,f)$ and if $(f,g)$ and $(g,h)$ are there also add $(f,h)$, then repeat all of the above again, etc. You will obtain some bigger subset $C$ of $A\times A$. After that, you can say that what you need is the quotient of $A$ by the equivalence relation

Comment: as follows: $f\sim g$ iff $(f,g)\in C$. Now note that we have not ensured $T\ne F$ here, and indeed as Andrej asked and as seen from Keith's answer, this might fail, i. e. after generating $C$ from all these pairs, it may happen that $(T,F)$ gets into $C$ too.

Comment: (and I forgot to add that if $(f1,g1)$ and $(f2,g2)$ are in $C$, then $(f1+f2,g1+g2)$ also must be in $C$)

Comment: so C is ... the space of all possible equational conclusions? thats going to explode :) but thanks for explaining the concept!

Comment: @propaganda sure, you need some kind of normal forms to keep control of it. Also note that this was for the case when $xy=yx$ also holds. If not, you get even more polynomials like $mT\alpha_1F+n\alpha_1FTF+pF^2T^3F^5+...$. In a sense they are actually simpler to work with, since they satisfy less relations. But then, it is not clear for me anymore why the identities you have do not include things like $\alpha_1F+F\delta_1+\beta_1T+T\varepsilon_1+\eta_1F\zeta_1+\phi_1T\psi_1+\gamma_1=T$ and alike

Comment: all the equations coefficients should be on the same side within products (I showed all on left) with respect to T or F. If not my proof (that the trade-off is unnecessary - assuming the existence of such a model) breaks down. So it is a requirement...

Comment: I did not check carefully enough but I believe in this case Keith's argument still works without having commutativity of multiplication

Comment: One more thing though. In principle there are also equalities of the form, say, $\alpha_1F+\beta_1T+mF+nT+\gamma_1=T$ possible, where $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers. Are these also to be excluded?

Comment: In such a form $m_1$, $m_2$ and $n_1$, $n_2$ should be constant per set of four $\land$ or $\lor$ rules. But then it is only a special case of the models I request since they can be written in the form above. So it does not provide extra wiggle room! Finding such a model would be fine and can be trivially transformed to a model I seek by $\gamma_1=m_1F+n_1T+\gamma^{'}_1$. Finding a contradiction for your modified version would however not necessarily qualify as a contradiction for my question!

Comment: Keith's argument does rely on commutativity of multiplication, the coefficients of $x_{ij}$ on one side of the equation are $A_iA_j$ but $A_jA_i$ on the other...

Comment: If you let mathematicians know about the "unoptimized" problem you're trying to solve, I think that would be increase the chances that someone will come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: there is no finite set $S$ with these properties, but there is an infinite set $S$ with the properties. I have posted the explanation [on math*overflow*.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270999)

---

**Edit 6/27/17.**

I will edit my answer on this page to respond to questions below about the my original, longer answer [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270999)

1. **I understand that considering increasing powers of $\alpha$ at after a number of values the powers must end up in a repeating cycle. But given x initial powers and repetition length y, I fail to deduce that for some $k$: $\alpha^{2k}=\alpha^k$.**

Suppose that $\alpha^r = \alpha^{r+s}$ for some $s>0$. By multiplying this equality by $\alpha^{r'-r}$ for $r'-r\geq 0$ we get $\alpha^{r'}=\alpha^{r'+s}$ for any $r'\geq r$. Also, by traversing the final cycle multiple times we get $\alpha^{r'}=\alpha^{r'+s}=\alpha^{r'+2s} = \cdots$, or just $\alpha^{r'}=\alpha^{r'+s'}$ for any $r'\geq r$ and any multiple $s'$ of $s$.

Using this information, let $k=r'=s'$ be some multiple of $s$ that is at least as large as $r$; i.e. $k=r'=s'=ms\geq r$ for some positive $m$. Then $\alpha^{2k}=\alpha^{r'+s'}=\alpha^{r'}=\alpha^k$.

2. **Another point is that my original question here does not assume identity element, which is assumed in the commutativity part.**

There are at least two reponses to this objection: (i) an identity element can be adjoined if necessary, provided we are working with the standard definition of "polynomial", or (ii) the solution can be slightly modified to avoid any reference to an identity element. I'll explain (ii) here. First, I copy the relevant part of the solution:

Let $\overline{\mu}(x,y,z)=x + \alpha\beta y + \alpha\gamma z + D$.
That is, delete the coefficient
$\alpha$ from $x$ in the polynomial expression
for $\mu(x,y,z)$ (or think of it
as replacing $\alpha$ with $1$).
Observe that the semimodule
polynomials $\mu (x,y,z)$ and $\overline{\mu}(x,y,z)$
both have the same restriction to $\{T',F'\} = \{\alpha T, \alpha F\}$,
since the polynomials only differ in their $x$-coefficient,
the inputs all have $\alpha$ as a prefix, and $\alpha^2 = \alpha$.
For example, 
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\overline{\mu}(F',T',T')&=
\overline{\mu}(\alpha F,\alpha T,\alpha T)\\
&=(\alpha F) +
\alpha\beta (\alpha T) + \alpha\gamma (\alpha T) + D\\
&= 
\alpha(\alpha  F) +
\alpha\beta (\alpha T) + \alpha\gamma (\alpha T) + D\\
&= 
\mu(\alpha F,\alpha T,\alpha T)\\
&=
\mu(F',T',T').
\end{array}$$

---

The above can be rewritten as follows:

Let $\overline{\mu}(x,y,z)=\alpha x + \alpha\beta\alpha y + \alpha\gamma\alpha z + D$.
That is, right multiply the coefficients of $y$ and $z$ by $\alpha$
in the polynomial expression
for $\mu(x,y,z)$.
Observe that the semimodule
polynomials $\mu (x,y,z)$ and $\overline{\mu}(x,y,z)$
both have the same restriction to $\{T',F'\} = \{\alpha T, \alpha F\}$,
since the polynomials only differ in their $y$ and $z$-coefficient,
the inputs all have $\alpha$ as a prefix, and $\alpha^2 = \alpha$.
For example, 

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\overline{\mu}(F',T',T')&=
\overline{\mu}(\alpha F,\alpha T,\alpha T)\\
&=\alpha(\alpha F) +
\alpha\beta \alpha(\alpha T) + \alpha\gamma \alpha(\alpha T) + D\\
&=\alpha(\alpha F) +
\alpha\beta (\alpha^2 T) + \alpha\gamma (\alpha^2 T) + D\\
&= 
\alpha(\alpha  F) +
\alpha\beta (\alpha T) + \alpha\gamma (\alpha T) + D\\
&= 
\mu(\alpha F,\alpha T,\alpha T)\\
&=
\mu(F',T',T').
\end{array}$$

---

The key point is that, in either version of the argument,  the coefficient of $x$ in $\overline{\mu}(x,y,z) = \alpha x + \alpha\beta\alpha y + \alpha\gamma\alpha z + D$, which is $\alpha$, commutes with the coefficients of $y$ and $z$, since $\alpha(\alpha\beta\alpha) = \alpha\beta\alpha = (\alpha\beta\alpha)\alpha$ and $\alpha(\alpha\gamma\alpha) = \alpha\gamma\alpha = (\alpha\gamma\alpha)\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the proof, you must have spent quite some time on it! I fail to grasp most steps, since I am not a mathematician, I will try to convert the proof to MetaMath, for confidence, once I succeed I will definitely accept the answer! In the mean time, how should I contact you (email?) if I get stuck or have questions?

Comment: I need to spend more time to try and understand the proof, but I have some specific questions for now: I understand that considering increasing powers of $\alpha$ at after a number of values the powers must end up in a repeating cycle. But given x initial powers and repitition length y, I fail to deduce that for some k: $\alpha^{2k}=\alpha^k$ ... Another point is that my original question here does not assume identity element, which is assumed in the commutativity part.

Comment: @propaganda: I'll edit my response here to answer these questions.